# Twitter authentication - I can't see my app in my apps

Tags: php, html, zend-framework

I have created a twitter connection with PHP.

Everything is fine until I click on the SIGN IN button on the authentication page.

[image: twitter authentication]

If I click on the Sign in , and try to check this app in MY apps , it's not there. In my opinion  it's not assigned. This is the main problem, and I didn't find anything how can I resolve it.

Next time when I click on the login button I got this screen again.

You need to know: I have used [oauth_authenticate_url](https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate), instead of authorize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once twitter re-directs to your Callback URL, run an API call to test it's worked. It may constantly keep re-directing you back to the Authentication Page if you have not saved the Auth Token and Secret.

So when you go to make your next API call if these haven't been saved then it will try and re-auth to get the token and secret again.

Comment: Yes, you are possibly right. Otherwise, I can't understand why this app not available after my first authentication on my twitter my apps site. This is the main problem.

Comment: Okey, session saving was needed.

Comment: Excellent. Good luck with your app.